# How to use data obtained from two response and use it in a third fetch?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am hitting two API end points to obtain `totalPolice` and `totalZone` and I wish to use these two variables in a third response obtained from the third fetch request.

```
// First API to get totalPolice
fetch("url1").then(
    res=>{
        res.json().then(
            data=>{
                    totalPolice = data.length
            }
        )
    }
);
// Second API to get total Zones
fetch("url2").then(
    res=>{
        res.json().then(
            data=>{
                    totalZone = data.length
            }
        )
    }
);
// Third API that uses totalPolice and totalZone variable
fetch("url3").then(
    res=>{
        res.json().then(
            data=>{
                    data.length = totalPolice + totalZone // dummy equation
            }
        )
    }
);
```

The problem I am facing is that these fetch requests are happening asynchronously and I wish to make my third fetch wait till the first two request finish so that I can use the data in my third request.
I am new to javascript so I just wanted to know if there is a good way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function getData() {
    res1 = await fetch(url1)
    totalPolice = await res1.json()

    res2 = await fetch(url2)
    totalZone = await res2.json()

    res3 = await fetch(url3)
    data3 = await res3.json()

    data3.length = totalPolice + totalZone
}
```

I haven't tested it.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to doing this is like this, i think

```
async function getAllData(){
    firstApi = await (await fetch('url1')).json();
    secondApi = await (await fetch('url2')).json();
    finalCall = await (await fetch('url from first and second')).json();
    return finalCall;
}
```

then your function will return the promise and you can reflect the changes in the UI in the then block of this async function